# populate values in columns of excel sheet using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, export-to-excel

I am trying to generate a script which stores my values to a excel sheet in column wise.
Eg:
I have Stationery, books category, and pen, pencil, You can win book items. I need the following output.

```
____________________________________
|_ Stationery______ | Pen __________|
|__Books___________ | You can win   |
|___________________|_______________|
```

Comment: Hi all, 
            Can anyone update me

Answer (score 0):

**Edits based on comments:** 
If I assume your starting file is `file`:

```
cat file

a, b,
c, d,
```

then replace a, b, c, and d with another array of items:

```
array=("a" "b" "c" "d")
array2=("Stationery" "Pen" "Books" "You can win")
a=$(<file)
for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};++i)) do
   a=${a//"${array[i]}"/"${array2[i]}"} 
   echo "$a" > file.csv
done
```

Of course `array2` can contain anything you want.
If you want the .xlsx file type, do this using `ssconvert`:

```
ssconvert --export-type=Gnumeric_Excel:xlsx file.csv file.xlsx
```

Here's the man page for `ssconvert`
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssconvert1.html. That's installed as part of [gnumeric](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnumeric).

Comment: Suppose I am storing variables in the columns of excel. Like example, I store a=hostname, b= date, c=IP address. How will I store this. I must get the output like

hostname in place of Stationery, date in place of pen

Comment: @user3318138 it's very possible I don't understand, but the edit shows one way using bash to replace your starting a,b,c,d array with whatever you want and output a .csv file.